# FORTIFY_SOURCE and Og optimization level

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++, memory-safety

Is it possible to use `-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` option (or `=1`) along with `-Og` optimization level? [The patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2004-09/msg02055.html) which introduces `FORTIFY_SOURCE` contains a comment `/* Object size checking is only intended for -O[s123]. */`.

It is 2004 year. And I don't know when `-Og` key is introduced (maybe later).

Which optimizations (optimization flags) `FORTIFY_SOURCE` requires namely?

Comment: You don't need `-Wp`, just use plain `-D`. GCC is clever enough to forward it to preprocessor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortification requires `__OPTIMIZE__` macro greater than 0:

```
$ cat /usr/include/features
#if defined _FORTIFY_SOURCE && _FORTIFY_SOURCE > 0 \
    && __GNUC_PREREQ (4, 1) && defined __OPTIMIZE__ && __OPTIMIZE__ > 0
# if _FORTIFY_SOURCE > 1
#  define __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL 2
```

`-Og` is no different from other `-O` flags in defining `__OPTIMIZE__`:

```
$ gcc -E -Og -dM -x c /dev/null 2>&1 | grep OPTIMIZE
#define __OPTIMIZE__ 1
```

so you should be fine.

You can ask Glibc developers to update the comment.